# Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск) c++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

я написал вот такую программку:

```
//includes
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

//namespaces
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

//defines
#define RETURN return 0

//main
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru"); //locale
    const auto _BEFORE_ = high_resolution_clock::now(); //start timer (for time account)
    srand(time(0));

    //Create Array
    int CountArrayIn_arr2D = 2;
    int CountElementsIn_arr1D = 3;
    int **arr2D = new int*[CountArrayIn_arr2D];

    //Generate Array
    for(int i = 0; i < CountArrayIn_arr2D; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < CountElementsIn_arr1D; j++) {
            arr2D[i][j] = rand() % 30 + 1;
        }
    }

    //Print Array
    for(int i = 0; i < CountArrayIn_arr2D; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < CountElementsIn_arr1D; j++) {
            cout<<"\033[34m"<<arr2D[i][j]<<"\033[0m\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


    /*Clean memory*/
    for(int i = 0; i < CountArrayIn_arr2D; i++) {
        delete[] arr2D[i];
    }
    delete[] arr2D;

    //time account
    const auto _AFTER_ = high_resolution_clock::now();
    const float TIME_FOR_PROGRAM = duration_cast<milliseconds>(_AFTER_-_BEFORE_).count();
    cout<<"\n\n Programm completed in "<<TIME_FOR_PROGRAM<<"ms"<<endl;
    RETURN;
}
```

и пишет: [image: запуск программы(не компиляция, а запуск) на Ubuntu]

у меня 2 вопроса.
1) что значит стек сброшен на диск? на жесткий диск? удалится ли он самостоятельно? если нет то как удалить?
2) как это решить и почему это вообще произошло?

Comment: ".exe" излишне, BTW. Вы находитесь в программном окружении, которое опознаёт исполняемые файлы по другим признакам, нежели кусок их имени.

Comment: не переживай, я знаю, просто мне так больше нравится)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас явная ошибка работы с памятью. Вызов `new` происходит один раз, а вызов `delete`?

---

Здесь происходит выделение массива указателей на `int`:

```
int **arr2D = new int*[CountArrayIn_arr2D];
```

Чтобы получить двумерный массив, нужно еще в каждый указатель выделить свой блок памяти:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CountArrayIn_arr2D; i++) 
{
    arr2D[i] = new int[CountElementsIn_arr1D];
//             ^^^^^^^

    for (int j = 0; j < CountElementsIn_arr1D; j++) 
    {
        // делаем что нужно
    }
}
```

Comment: а стек сброшен на диск что значит? у меня потеря памяти на жестком диске?

Answer (score 3):

"Стек памяти сброшен на диск" — это [весьма-а вольный] перевод фразы "[Core dumped](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)". На диске в текущем каталоге создаётся файл с именем "core". Сам он не удалится, но он — самый обычный файл, который вы можете удалить когда захотите.

Файл core также сам по себе является кратчайшим путём к ответу на вопрос номер 2. Если ваш бинарник собран с опцией компилятора "-g", то вы можете запустить отладчик с командной строкой в виде "gdb -c core main.exe". Отладчик автоматически окажется на той строке, которая вызвала segmentation fault. О работе в gdb рекомендую почитать его документацию, она обширна и исчерпывающа.

Comment: я немного не понял где лежит файл core? и много ли он весит

Comment: Лежит — в текущем каталоге, там, где были, когда запускали программу. Весит - ну, по разному, в зависимости от упавшей программы, но не больше, чем `ulimit -c`. Это её память, в общем. В случае, если размер файла core оказался бы больше, чем `ulimit -c` (если только оно не равно нулю), core не дампится. При `ulimit -c`, равном нулю, лимита на размер core нет.

Comment: его тут нет. это хорошо или плохо?

Comment: я проверил его нет там где лежит main.cpp. Писал ls -l -a

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/14332634  ,  а у меня бросаются в текущий каталог...

Answer (score 1):

чел, ты забыл объявить элементы массивов в массиве)